# Dynamically modify web.xml and server.xml

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, jboss

My web application uses a **JDBC** data source. 
It's defined as a *resource-ref* in **web.xml**:

```
 <resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/dss</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
 </resource-ref>
```

And, further configurations in **server.xml** :

```
<Context debug="0" docBase="dss" path="/dss" reloadable="true"><Resource auth="Container" defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         maxActive="10" maxIdle="5" maxWait="5000" name="jdbc/dss" password="admin" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dss45" username="root" />
    </Context>
```

The problem being that I can only fetch the data source access parameters dynamically (I am using an OpenShift based Paas).

Is there a way I can start **Tomcat(7.x)** without errors, and then fill in these access parameters programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Providing the datasource by the container (e.g. tomcat) is done (probably among other reasons) so that the application does not even get to know the connection and password - thus can't loose it. Getting the datasource from the container is not mandatory if that's not what you need: You can create a datasource from whatever data you get.

Another option - but probably more complex - is to create your own [DatasourceFactory](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceFactory.html) that looks up and fills in the required parameters on its own. This would leave the allocation of the Datasource in tomcat and your application could just continue to look up whatever datasource is provided to it.

Comment: Can you point me to a resource I can use as a reference to implement my own DatasourceFactory?

Comment: The interface is quite narrow - just look at the implementation you find in tomcat and replace the parts where the parameters are read from configuration xml with whereever you get the data from. Package that in a new class and add it to the classpath. Shouldn't be hard.